# Moltin Cart, Laravel and Angular JS – looping through JS object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I'm using a Moltin Cart which I want to loop through, so I can read it in Angular JS and then

I load the cart into a variable, which I'd like to `<div ng-repeat-start="item in cart.contents">` and loop through the items in the cart.

The issue I'm having is really a pretty basic JavaScript issue, that if I `console.log` the `cart.contents` I get this:

```
Object{ 
   33bb9f991617377b9b8333a79ca9ce2c: Object { ... cart contents... },
   1ba14b804d0d81e49397b004e5f1c6d1: Object { ... cart contents... },
   33bb9f991617377b9b8333a79ca9ce2c: Object { ... cart contents... },
}
```

Is there a way that I can fix this either in:

- Laravel
- Angular JS
- or Classic JavaScript

Comment: What do you want instead? An array of objects?

Comment: You can `angular.forEach` it to get cart contents.

Comment: disclaimer: I'm a massive angular noob. How do I ng-repeat with a `angular.forEach`?

Comment: @Djave You would have to loop over the object in your controller with angular.forEach and populate an array with the values you want on each iteration. Then use new array as the object to which you will apply the ng-repeat directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.objectOfObjects = {
        "ASDF": { name: 'First', price: 100 },
        "QWER": { name: 'Second', price: 200 },
        "FGHJ": { name: 'Third', price: 500 }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        When iterating over an object of objects, there is no guarantee about the order:
        <div ng-repeat-start="item in objectOfObjects">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat-end>{{item.price}}<br/><br/></div>
    </div>
</body>
```